# Recovering media which is deleted month before from android 10 mobile storage

Tags: recovery-mode, internal-storage, factory-reset, data-recovery

I have deleted a some media files month before, then I used my mobile as usual. Yesterday I performed a factory reset to mobile clean since it's storage is full. Now I need to get back my media which I deleted month before. Any possibility for this?

Comment: If your phone cam with Android 8 or newer then it should be encrypted by default which means data recovery after a factory is absolute impossible because the used encryption key is gone.

Comment: Hey @Robert Thank you, are you certain with this?